# how to get CPU load from VxWorks programmatically?

Tags: c, vxworks, rtos

I have a device that runs on VxWorks, and I would like to know, how to retrieve the total CPU load? I know the "spyLib", but unfortunately, it is not supported on my system.

is there any way to measure/calculate/retrieve the total load on my single-core CPU?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your system and what its design is.

One way is to create a task at the lowest priority that is nothing more than an idle loop.
You could then use taskSwitchHookAdd to detect whenever you switched in and out of this idle task and calculate the time delta between switching in and out.

The problem with this is that now, you CPU is NEVER idle since the task at priority 255 is consuming all the spare CPU cycles.  This might or might not be an issue for your system.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer, however, as you as already mentioned, the problem with the suggested solution is the CPU will be fully utilized. I wonder if there is a better approach, VxWorks build-in function, or even what is the "common" approach to measure the system load on vxWorks?